# Dynamic query in Postgres over db link

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function which will go over a DB LINK and do a count of object types belonging to a user and then store that value (I will insert this value into a table later so I can compare counts from my local DB with the remote one). I can build the SQL dynamically and it looks right but when it gets called over a DB link using the below I can't get it to accept the single quotes. Is there a way to plug this in for queries over a db link?

```
DO $$
DECLARE
sqlSmt text;
v_new_count NUMERIC:=0;
item record;

begin
 sqlSmt = null;

 FOR item IN
 (select nsp.nspname schema, cls.relkind obj_type from pg_class cls 
 join pg_roles rol on rol.oid = cls.relowner 
 join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = cls.relnamespace
 where nsp.nspname like 'dwh%' 
 group by nsp.nspname, cls.relkind 
 order by nsp.nspname, cls.relkind limit 10)
 LOOP

 sqlSmt = 'select * from dblink(''old_live'',''select count(*) from pg_class cls
 join pg_roles rol on rol.oid = cls.relowner
 join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = cls.relnamespace
 where nsp.nspname = '''||item.schema||''' and cls.relkind='''||item.obj_type||''') as total_count(total_count numeric)';

 EXECUTE sqlSmt INTO v_new_count;
 raise notice '%', sqlSmt;
 raise notice '%, %, %', item.schema, item.obj_type, v_new_count;

 END LOOP;

END $$;
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "dwh_10"
LINE 6:  where nsp.nspname = 'dwh_10' and cls.relkind='S') as total_...
                              ^
QUERY:  select * from dblink('old_live','select count(*) from pg_class cls
 join pg_roles rol
 on rol.oid = cls.relowner
 join pg_namespace nsp
 on nsp.oid = cls.relnamespace
 where nsp.nspname = 'dwh_10' and cls.relkind='S') as total_count(total_count numeric)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 27 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: You have too little quoting.  You should use some alternative quote symbol to do some of the layers of quoting, to avoid the need to have 7 single quotes in a row.  Also, use FORMAT to assembled the strings.  currently all 3 single quotes before 'dwh_10' are getting consumed before any of them get around to quoting 'dwh_10' itself.

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation should solve this problem:

Examples :

```
SELECT '''';
SELECT E'\''; 
SELECT $$'$$;  
SELECT $$ SELECT * FROM test WHERE name='test' ;$$ ; 
 
 sqlSmt = 'select * from dblink(''old_live'',$$select count(*) from pg_class cls
 join pg_roles rol on rol.oid = cls.relowner
 join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = cls.relnamespace
 where nsp.nspname = '''||item.schema||''' and cls.relkind='''||item.obj_type||''') as total_count(total_count numeric)$$;'
```

The $$ should solve the problem in string manipulation for the second level.